# Why in the song "I miss you" by Blink-182, the singer pronounces something like "yad" instead of "head"?

Tags: pronunciation, lyrics

In the phrase "You're already the voice inside my head", the pronunciation the singer uses for "head" is  bit confusing, I was wondering if it was a "slang" or other particular way of pronunciation of the word. Is it correct?

Comment: Just an odd way of running "my head" together and eliding the "h." He probably wouldn't pronounce it that way in speech.

Comment: One of the reasons his singing makes my skin crawl

Comment: Hmm. I thought there was a question about this in the past, but I can't find it.

Comment: Pronunciation in songs can be idiosyncratic, following poetic rules rather than natural language rules. Which is to say it could easily be because he's artistically drawing out a syllable, not necessarily following any usual elision rule, just to 'sound' good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's dropping the *h* to sound British, and slurring it together with the *y* from *my*.

The “pop-punk voice” or “pop-punk accent” [has a very interesting history](http://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/i-made-a-linguistics-professor-listen-to-a-blink-182-song-and-analyze-the-accent). (That article references “I Miss You,” though not that line.) In large part, it's about emulating a particular British accent that's associated with early punk. From the article:

> As an ode to the Clash, a lot of their singers adopted a sort of faux-British accent. “I'm an American guy faking an English accent faking an American accent,” Green Day lead singer Billie Joe Armstrong told Rolling Stone in 1994.

Comment: +1 for the explanation for why he's dropping the *h*. Once you drop the *h*, of course you'll slur it together with the *y* from *my*.